# Cannot install @angular/cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to work on angular2 for which I have installed nodeJS. I have followed the steps given here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites but there seems to be an issue. Here's what I did in the Command Prompt(Admin):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>node -v  
v6.10.1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm -v  
3.10.10

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli  
[ ..............] / loadRequestedDeps: sill install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
```

My command prompt is stuck at this command and shows no sign of response. I will be glad if there are any suggestions on solving this issue of mine. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: If there is not network problems, I think you just have to wait for the download.

Comment: Hi @Pengyy, I have no network issues. I have waited for an hour now and then posted this issue here to seek some help

Comment: have  you tried to reach https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli form your browser?

Comment: Yes, I have. I am waiting for a response. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5727

Comment: @VisheshSingh looks like a network issue, you might want to try `-verbose` to see  verbose logs `npm install -g @angular/cli  -verbose` it'll tell you what  exactly it's stuck on.

some additional things to try: turn off antivirus if you have any, if you are on vpn try disconnecting.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Here is my debug.log

Answer (score 4):

Make sure.,you already installed nodejs.

1. npm install -g angular-cli
2. ng help
3. ng new PROJECT_NAME
   cd PROJECT_NAME
   ng serve
4. ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201 --live-reload-port 49153

Answer (score 2):

This command solved this problem for me:

```
npm install -g rimraf
```

The TLS key was a real problem and also install windows-tools does not help. After rimraf and using the right proxy settings and node_modules destination I can install angular-cli.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try from the users directory C:\Users\userName or PC name just as shown in the below figure, and make sure you're not limited to any network related issues !

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/87/50/24/87502456dd8043729b794bf00ee2c7e7.jpg

Comment: That did not help either. Its stuck at the same thing

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html please try these you might succeed

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

Global Package :

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Local Package :

```
rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem. Press `Ctrl + C` in the command Prompt. It will continue and it will not exit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run "**`npm install`**" inside this project folder to install all
   dependencies.
2. Make sure you use the latest version of the CLI (upgrade guide
   below)
3. Run "**`ng serve`**" to see the app in action.

Then,

Run the below commands to upgrade the latest version of the CLI - only use "sudo" on Mac/ Linux.

1. sudo **`npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli`**
2. sudo **`npm install -g @angular/cli`**

Answer (score 0):

uninstall node.js

delete all node_modules from your directory

delete npm from AppData>Roaming>

delete npm_cache and all newly generated node files from the c:\users[username} directory.

install node.js

add local path as:

new>PATH>c:\users[username}\AppData\Roaming\npm

keep this before Temp path

in cmd: `npm -v node -v C:\Users\693272>npm install -g @angular/cli`

`ng -v`

(here 'ng' error should not come)

and now you can go to some other directory also and create your new project as

everything installed is set globally

C:\Users\693272>`cd /`

C:>`d:`

D:>`ng new app1 -d`

HOPE THIS HELPS!

Answer (score 0):

Open PowerShell as admin:

- **Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned**
- **npm cache clean --force**
- **npm install -g npm@latest**
- **npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/**
- **npm install -g @angular/cli --verbose**

Answer (score 0):

1. Start > Run > AppWiz.cpl > Uninstall node.js
2. Delete  the node install directory removing remaining folders and files
3. Delete npm folder from Start > Run > %AppData%   (AppData\Roaming)
4. If it exists delete npm-cache from the c:\users[username} directory
5. Install node.js the Latest Version and please use the default **C:\Program Files\nodejs** install path.
6. Open Cmd:

---

```
C:\Users\Jeremy>node -v
v17.1.0

C:\Users\Jeremy>npm -v
8.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nmp via Nvm without node case:**

In my case, I had installed npm via nvm on fresh Windows, without installing node first.

**The Fix**

- Uninstall all npm versions.
- Install node.
- Install npm via nvm again.

**Angular Cli** installation and all other **npm commands** worked fine after.