# NPM stucks when installing latest angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install

Wanted to install latest angular in order to install angular 15. However when trying to install angular CLI using the following command it always stuck in the same location.

```
npm install -g angular/cli@latest --verbose
```

Other parameters:
npm version - 9.8.0z
node version - 18.12.0

[image]

Read and followed the steps in the following too, but no luck.
Cannot install @angular/cli : [Cannot install @angular/cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082329/cannot-install-angular-cli)

Can someone help me on this?

Last part of the npm log file:

```
23 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
24 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/viraj/.npm/_logs/2023-07-17T06_04_25_688Z-
25 verbose logfile /home/viraj/.npm/_logs/2023-07-17T06_04_25_688Z-debug-0.log
26 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
27 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
28 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load Completed in 26ms
30 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 0ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
32 silly logfile done cleaning log files
33 timing idealTree:init Completed in 5ms
```

Comment: I've had some issues on Angular projects in the past of some packages that just take a very long time to install. So unless it throws an error I'd try being very patient and just letting it run for 15 minutes

Comment: Thank you Martijn for the sharing this information. I'll run it and keep this updated about the result.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work and stuck in the above screen.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many answers, still I have the issue with the same npm version. In summary there are 2 ways to bypass this error:

1. Use nvm and install different node/npm versions and trying for a successful combination (what I did)
2. Use yarn instead of npm